# XMLHttpRequest Status Returns Zero on Simple AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, browser

I am trying to learn vanilla JS AJAX by writing some basic API queries. However, I am receiving the status of the request as `0`. What does this mean and how could I fix this issue?

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("btn")

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener('click', makeRequest);
}

var httpRequest;

function makeRequest() {
  httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

  if (!httpRequest) {
    alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
    return false;
  }

  document.getElementsByClassName(".text").innerHTML= 'Loading Data ... '

  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
  httpRequest.open('GET', 'https://api.meetup.com/2/cities');
  httpRequest.send(null);

  function alertContents() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
        alert(httpRequest.responseText);
      } else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.' + httpRequest.status);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The following jQuery code does the job. I am still curious why the code above does not work.

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
  $('.text').text('Loading data . . . ');
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://api.meetup.com/2/cities',
    success: function(data) {
      $('.text').text(JSON.stringify(data));
    }, 
    dataType: "jsonp",
  })
});
```

Comment: What are you clicking to make the call?

Comment: A button with a class `btn`

Comment: I get this error `alert('There was a problem with the request.' + httpRequest.status);`

Comment: does the button have `type="button"`?

Comment: Yes, `<button class="btn" type="button">Fetch Api</button>`

Comment: Are you using file protocol or http? Is there any other errors in your developer console?

Comment: I am actually doing this in Codepen. Could this be an issue?

Comment: Why are people asking about the button and not the real problem?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes CORS.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.meetup.com/2/cities. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir status zero has 3 causes, form submission/page navigation, file protocol, and CORS.

Comment: However, one can open it in the browser and see JSON?

Comment: @epascarello Is one of the causes related to the button? o.O

Comment: @MadPhysicist Unless they have a public API, you will need to use a proxy. Plenty of dupes on stackoverflow about CORS

Comment: Does it make sense that jQuery can successfully make a call to this URL?

Answer (score 0):

Because "alertContents" is undefined at that point. You should declare the function before assign it to onreadystatechange.

You can check it with a console.log(typeof alertContents) before the assignment.

Comment: That is not the problem.